# Java install on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, installation, java

i'm new to linux and i was trying to install the java JDK with EE on ubuntu. I downloaded the .bin file (java_ ee_ sdk-5_08-jdk-6u17-linux.bin) from the sun site & followed the install instructions below (as root user instructions are from the sun website):

1. Download and check the download file size to ensure that you have downloaded the full, uncorrupted software bundle.

   2. Make sure that execute permissions are set on the self-extracting binary.

   Run these command:
   chmod +x java_ ee_ sdk-5_08-jdk-6u17-linux.bin

   3. Change directory to the location where you would like the files to be installed.

   The next step installs the JDK into the current directory.

   4. Run the self-extracting binary.

   Execute the downloaded file, prepended by the path to it. For example, if the file is in the current directory, prepend it with "./" (necessary if "." is not in the PATH environment variable):

   ./java_ ee_ sdk-5_08-jdk-6u17-linux.bin

I always get an 'No such file or directory'-error, i'm certain the path is correct & i'm not sure what else could be wrong...

I'm running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu 9.10 in Vmware workstation 8.5

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try typing `java` then pressing tab, it will type the rest for you to ensure there is no mistake. Although to install Java, you're doing it the hard way. You can use:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6XX-bin sun-java6XX-jre sun-java6XX-plugin
```

where XX is the current version number in the repositories, likely current. Although I'd recommend the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I'd suggest running this on any new Ubuntu machine that you intend to use as a desktop, it installs a bunch of stuff for:

> **Audio**
>
> - Ripping CDs
> - Converting your audio files and video to open formats
> - Using the iTunes Music Store
> - MP3
> - Playing or ripping CDs to AAC (.m4a) files
>
> **DVD**
>
> - Playing DVDs
> - Ripping DVDs
> - Playing Blu Ray and HD DVD
>
> **Web**
>
> - Playing Flash
> - Adobe Shockwave No native version.
>
> **Video**
>
> - Streaming Video
> - HelixPlayer
> - Realplayer
> - Smil
> - Apple Quicktime and RealVideo
>
> **Other**
>
> - Java
> - Installing popular fonts

the actual packages installed:

```
cabextract 
flashplugin-nonfree 
gsfonts-x11 
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg 
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad 
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse 
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly 
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse 
jackd 
java-common 
liba52-0.7.4 
libavcodec1d 
libavutil1d 
libcdaudio1 
libdvdread3 
libfaac0 
libfaad2-0 
libfreebob0 
libgsm1 
libid3tag0 
libjack0 
liblame0 
libltdl3 
libmad0 
libmjpegtools0c2a 
libmms0 
libmp4v2-0 
libmpcdec3 
libmpeg2-4 
libqt3-mt 
libquicktime1 
libsidplay1 
libsoundtouch1c2 
libx264-54 
libxvidcore4 
msttcorefonts 
odbcinst1debian1 
qjackctl 
sun-java6-bin 
sun-java6-jre 
sun-java6-plugin 
unixodbc 
unrar
```

Although keep in mind the [legal issues regarding patents](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats).

Comment: +1 ubuntu-restricted-extras is very useful, but be aware of the legal issues in the US if you have any respect for software patents (which I personally think are total rubbish and don't pay any attention to).

Comment: Yes that is important imformation. I added a link to the Ubuntu page on restricted formats which explains their take on free software, with accompanied links which explain the issues.