# streaming video on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, ubuntu-9.10, codec

I am trying to get streaming video to work on install of fully up to date Ubuntu 9.10.

For example: http://cbc.ca/video

I am guessing that the packages/codecs necessary cannot be distributed with Linux due to license issues.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install flash player for videos like that:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

If you want to install Java and some codecs and all those other goodies:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I've outlined what's included in the package [here](https://superuser.com/questions/65324/java-install-on-ubuntu/65326#65326).

Comment: Ok - thanks for the package suggestions. I've done all that and some sites like youtube and watch.ctv.ca work just fine.

I'm still having some trouble with http://cbc.ca/video

Now one thing I'm wondering - I recently did a big upgrade (possibly  including the kernel, not sure because didn't pay close attention during upgrade process).  I think I had ubuntu-restricted-extras installed prior to this upgrade.  Would it be advisable to uninstall/reinstall it?  If so, how would I do that without causing too much fallout with other packages on my system?

Comment: No it should be fine. You could try an apt-get update and see if a new one is available though. Maybe even update Firefox.

Comment: Ok - i've tried updating a few of the packages without making video on the CBC work.

For now I'm giving up modifying my system and have sent a support request into the CBC as maybe it is their problem with regards to Linux system compatibility.  I will update this post if/when I resolve the situation.